# A proper understanding of equality in salvation

Tags: hadith-interpretation, jahannam, doubts

It is narrated in: https://sunnah.com/mishkat:111

> I asked, “Messenger of God, what happens to the offspring of believers?’’ He replied, “They are joined to their parents." I asked, “Although they have done nothing, messenger of God” lie replied, “God knows best what they were doing.” I asked, “What happens to the offspring of polytheists?” He replied, “They are joined to their parents.” I asked, “Although they have done nothing?” He replied, “God knows best what they were doing.”

What is the meaning of this hadith? From my understanding, it is implied that those who are born in polytheist families, Allah has decreed that it is less likely for them to accept Islam under those circumstances, as a child will follow his guardians. If my understanding is correct, isn't this a bit unfair? Allah is essentially creating a child and giving him less chances to salvaged from eternal damnation in hell. Am I missing something here?